# tkz-euclide's \tkzMarkAngle "arc" option

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide, arc

I'm trying to adapt an example from the `tkz-euclide` manual (image below), where the arc is constructed by "three lines"... I assume that's achieved by adding the option `arc=lll` in the `\tkzMarkAngle` command.

[image]

So I try to create my own angle, but here's what I get with the code (the arc is supposed to show up where my mouse cursor is):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot} %Para fazer desenhos
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations,babel,patterns,fit}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(30:4){B}

\tkzDrawPolygon(A,O,B)
\tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll](A,O,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any ideas for a solution? Here's what I tried:

1. I tried using `arc=lll`, the result was an arc with a single line.
2. Specifying a `size` didn't help.
3. Using `arc=l`worked properly (producing an arc with a single line), but I need an arc with 2 or 3 lines.

I do not speak French, so reading the manual isn't really helping me. If someone knows a solution using `TikZ`, that'd be amazing, since I am not aware of TikZ having `\tkzMarkAngle` or `\tkzMarkSegment` alternatives...

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to assume that when setting a size for the angle, you didn't specify a length, such as in:

```
\tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll, size=1](A,O,B)
```

That's not going to do anything because `\tkzMarkAngle` needs a length, so you should write something like this instead (other lengths will work as well):

```
\tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll, size=1cm](A,O,B)
```

Comment: I have tried using something like `size=.4cm`, still didn't work.

Comment: @GuilhermeVargas It's working for me. Is your Tex distribution up to date?

Comment: I've updated everthing on `MiKTeX` Update Managers (Both "Admin" and not), except that on the Update Manager that is NOT "Admin", `miktex-tex4ht-base-2.9` is set to be repaired, and under that there's `pgf` to be updated from 3.0.0 to 3.0.1a... For some reason those don't work when I try to update them.

Comment: Talk about strange things. It "suddenly" started to work with my own code! I didn't restart the machine after all those updates.